# Django: Achieving "quasi-interface" like database model to effectively handle several subtypes

Tags: database, django, database-design

How would one model the following situation?  I've thought about this for a while and cannot determine an effective way to accomplish what I'm wanting to do.

I have a question class that has many answers.  Answers can be of many types.

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.OneToOneField(Question)
    date = models.DateField()

class CharAnswer(Answer):
    data = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class NumberAnswer(Answer):
    data = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=5)

class TimeAnswer(Answer):
    data = models.TimeField()

class ListAnswer(Answer):
    data = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=256)
    data_type = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

I would love to be able to do something like `Answers.objects.all.values_list('data')` and be able to aggregate all the heterogenous `data` fields.

I am open to a total redesign if I'm doing things in a sub-optimal way.  I've searched and searched, and I don't think this is an easy thing to accomplish.  Should I just store all the answer data in one table?

Comment: Sounds like [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) could help you.